# How to put data in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using `Highcharts.js` plugin and everything it's fine, but what I want to show is for example this data:

> 1, 5, 10, 20

The problem here is that every value it's displayed in one column and what I want is to display all the values in one column, so my question is what can I do to show my chart like I want? Here is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#xd').click(function() {
    draw();
  });
});

function draw() {
  var myArray = [];
  myArray = [1, 5, 10, 11, 8];

  $('#grafic').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Sampled Parts'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Data'],
      labels: {
        rotation: -33,
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: true,
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Resultados'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
          this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
          'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
      }
    },

    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'My Data',
      data: myArray
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>






<div id="grafic">
</div>

<button id="xd">Click</button>
```

If you see my code I have 5 columns and what I want is to have all the values in only one column but to be honest I don't have any idea of what can I do.

[Codepen code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpxjBR)

Comment: are you talking about stacking the values or just changing the labels? (see stacked columns chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked)

Comment: @ochi Yes! Good point, I want to stack all the values in one column instead of one column per value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stack the values, then you need to create multiple series (each with only one value in it, I guess).  Change it from this:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray = [1, 5, 10, 11, 8];
```

to this:

```
series: [{
      name: 'mydata',
      data: [1]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata2',
      data: [5]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata3',
      data: [10]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata4',
      data: [11]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata5',
      data: [8]
    }]
```

See **running sample below**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#xd').click(function() {
    draw();
  });
});

function draw() {
  $('#grafic').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Sampled Parts'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Data'],
      labels: {
        rotation: -33,
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: true,
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Resultados'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
          this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
          'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
      }
    },

    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    //  var myArray = [];
    //  myArray = [1, 5, 10, 11, 8];

    series: [{
      name: 'mydata',
      data: [1]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata2',
      data: [5]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata3',
      data: [10]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata4',
      data: [11]
    }, {
      name: 'mydata5',
      data: [8]
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="grafic">
</div>

<button id="xd">Click</button>
```

Comment: The only way to do this is create one serie for every value rigth?

Comment: @MiguelFlores As far as I know, yes (using Highcharts in any case.)  - this is because it's not expecting to draw only one data type (but many) and each column would require multiple data types (and a value for each type in that column)

Comment: Well, then this is the correct answer because I need to use highcharts, thanks for your help!

Comment: np, glad I could help